# Unlock full Developer options on Philips PFK5500/12

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, android-tv

I recently bought a TV with Android OS ([Philips PFK 5500/12](http://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/40PFT5500_12/5500-series-full-hd-slim-led-tv-powered-by-androidtm-with-pixel-plus-hd)).
This is not the tiptop very best, I know, but it was okay.
Also this is not exactly AndroidTV, but merley a predecossor running Android 5.1.

I successfully enabled the developer options, via the easter egg, but left confused because I don't see all settings like installation from foreign sources and others.
As it is my understanding, those settings are there, but artificially hidden by the vendor.

So my qestion is wether there is another hidden option to choose or not?

Comment: 'installation from foreign sources and others' - do you mean Installation from **unknown sources**? All android devices that I know show this option under **Security**. Are you sure that it isn't located there?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry for the misconception. Unknown sources is correct. 
I have to check out Security, but I strongly believe it isn't there too.

Comment: There is a chance that the ODM removed Unknown Sources as I didn't find it as a requirement for Google Play/Android Compatibility Definition Document. Long ago AT&T removed it from their earliest Android phones.

Comment: I didn't find them under security either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an update they are were just there.